# Selenium function does work on debug but not when running

Tags: java, css, selenium

I'm testing a webpage and I want to hover over a element, to test its color when hovered, and then I'm using the function:

```
  public void checkElementFontHoverColor(WebElement element, String expectedColor) {
    mouseOverOnElement(element);
    String currentColor = convertRgbaToHex(element.getCssValue("color"));
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedColor, currentColor);
}
```

Which function mouseOverOnElement implementation is:

```
   public void mouseOverOnElement(WebElement element) {
    Actions action = new Actions(getDriver());
    action.moveToElement(element).perform();
    waitSleep(10000L);
   }
```

This works good when debugging. However it is not working when running without debugging. What can I do to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At what point is checkElementFontHoverColor called in relation to mouseOverOnElement?

Comment: When you say _**when debugging**_, do you mean when stepping through the code? You probably need to check what the color is before you hover, and wait for it to change. Or do some other kind of wait to indicate that the changes to the page caused by the hover have completed before moving on to the next step. It looks like you have that waitSleep there, but I don't know what that does exactly...

Comment: You might also need to grab the color as part of your actions so it doesn't **move** off the element before checking the color.

Comment: Instead of waitSleep use following action.moveToElement(element).pause(1000).build().perform();